# If $\forall \epsilon >0$ there is no element in $S$ greater than $s$ and $\exists$ element in $S$ greater than $s-\epsilon$, then $s$ is the supremum

Tags: real-analysis

I have proved the reversed direction. However, I've totally no idea on how to prove this.

$S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $s$ is the supremum

If $\forall \epsilon >0$ there is no element in $S$ greater than $s$ and there is element in $S$ greater than $s-\epsilon$, then $s$ is the supremum of $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are told there is no element of $S$ which is greater than $s$. Thus $s$ is an upper bound of $S$.

To show that $s$ is the supremum of $S$, we need to show $S$ has no  upper bound cheaper than $s$.

Suppose to the contrary that $s_1\lt s$ is an upper bound of $S$. Let $\epsilon=\frac{s-s_1}{2}$. Then by our assumption there is an element $x$ of $S$ which is greater than $s-\epsilon$. Now from $x\gt s-\epsilon$ and $\epsilon=\frac{s-s_1}{2}$, conclude that $x\gt s_1$, contradicting the assumption that $s_1$ is an upper bound of $S$.

**Remark:** That $x\gt s_1$ is clear from drawing a picture. If we want to be very formal, we can write as follows: 
$$x\gt s-\epsilon=s-\frac{s-s_1}{2}=\frac{s+s_1}{2}.$$ 
Thus $x-s_1
\gt \frac{s+s_1}{2}-s_1=\frac{s-s_1}{2}\gt 0$.